# if there is already '1' in the database, database won't accept another '1'. It will only accept '0'

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this column `is_default` which accepts 1 or 0 depending if the 'Default' checkbox is checked or not.

My `create.blade.php`

```
<div class="form-check disabled">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="hidden" value='0' name="is_default">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value='1' name="is_default">
   Default Variant
  </label>
</div>
```

My `VariantsController@store`:

```
    DB::transaction(function() use ($request){
        $variant = Variant::firstorCreate([
            //some more code here
            'is_default'        => $request->is_default
        ]);

    });
```

In my variants table, I have a `product_id` which is a foreign key to products table. and I have the `is_default` column. Now, A Product, can have many Variants but there should only be one default variant per product.

So it's something like, (if the checkbox is checked)

```
$checkdefault = Variant::where('product_id',$product)...
```

find if there is a '1' in `is_default` and if there is no '1' then the database will save it, else it will save a zero and return a splash that says "there should only be one default variant"

I don't know if my explanation explains it well, but I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is it set to unique?

Comment: it can't be set to unique because there are a lot of products in the variants table(therefore there are many product_id). I am just only pertaining to the entries with the same product_id

Comment: Before you store a new default, set the `is_default` field to `0` for all the other rows with that product ID. I doubt there's a way to make this happen automatically, you just have to code it yourself.